# Can I ask azure for the status of other instances in my role?

Tags: azure

If i enumerate role.instances that just shows the static role configuration. I.e if I take down an instance the enumerate results are still the same

Answer (score 3):

You can use internal endpoints to communicate with each instance. You define these in the service definition files of your roles and then communicate using the RoleEnvironment.Roles[] and instances. The [HelloFabric Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-HelloFabric-007c5917) shows how you can do this. You can also read about the pattern on the [Windows Azure Blog.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2009/11/24/new-endpoint-options-enable-additional-application-patterns.aspx)